Find source code of ubuntu?

as ubuntu is open source type os so i wonder where i can find all the codes of ubuntu os specific of the install code which run while installation of ubuntu os.
And very helpful if you also tell about the languages used and actual execution process of installation.
helpful if refer link specified is also linked with answer
i needed it to work on my idea so needed raw code that can be edited using editors.


Ubuntu like other Linux distributions is a collection of kernel, init system, display server, windowing system, userspace applications etc. … Most of these are open source and have their own repos with source code publicly available on the Internet … However, none open source packages might be available for install by the user.

Far too broad.  Please read to https://askubuntu.com/help q's need to be about a specific issue when using Ubuntu

I just wanted source code of ubuntu

Does this answer your question? Where can I find the source code of Ubuntu?

seen that answer but it doesn't satisfactory to me.

It's too broad. Be more specific.

The company behind Ubuntu is Canonical, which is involved in multiple Open Source projects. Canonical uses, as many other open source projects, too, Github as a platform to host project code. The Github repos (currently around 1200) of Canonical can be found here: Link to Canonical's Github.
As you as specifically about the installer: it is called Ubuntu Desktop Provision and the code can be found at Github as well: Link to ubuntu-desktop-provision.
Ubuntu Server uses a different installed named Subiquity, source code is at: Link to Subiquity Github repo.
